# How to make overlapping buttons?

Tags: user-interface, button, godot

Is there a nice way to make two buttons overlap in such a way that when their intersection is cliked, both buttons will be activated at the same time?

[image: Like this]

I tried to change *mouse_filter* parameter, but it didn't gave any result.

Comment: What have you tried so far? Please edit your post to have any code for your best attempt. Pros and cons to each, do you prefer to use the Button class or making your own button?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have 2 options as far as I know:

1- Use TouchScreenButton node instead of Button node derived from Control. It allows the functionality you ask for.

2- Setting mouse filter to "pass" allows event to be passed to parent nodes. If your button nodes are siblings of each other it won't have any effect but if one of them is parent of another you can press both of them at the same time.